# DEL set of keys in Redis

Tags: redis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In redis, how do i remove keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799063/in-redis-how-do-i-remove-keys)

How do I delete all keys matching a pattern in Redis. I want to DEL images:* but it doesn't work.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
 1) "images:red"
 2) "images:axe"
 3) "images:green"
 4) "images:elephant"
 5) "images:banana"
 6) "images:taco bell"
 7) "images:potato"
 8) "images:purple"
 9) "images:blue"
10) "images:finch"
11) "images:meatloaf"
```