# Delete redis key matching pattern using ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

I want to delete all redis keys defined under namespace "datetime_filter" in ruby (maintenance task).
How to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
 $redis.del(datetime_filter_key)
```

and follow following approach -

[In redis, how do i remove keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799063/in-redis-how-do-i-remove-keys)

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do this if you don't want to block the server is to use the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command. The command will provide you an iterator returning only the keys matching your pattern if you wish (in this case it is appropriate to use the `MATCH` option for sure). The Ruby script will just have to iterate and delete.

So:

```
WHILE keys = SCAN MATCH datetime_filter*
    FOREACH key in keys DEL key
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```rb
Rails.cache.redis.keys.grep(/pattern/).each do |k|
  Rails.cache.redis.del(k)
end
```